# LDO temperature expectation

Tags: temperature, ldo

I've a TLF80511TF 5V LDO regulator, which I *think* gets a bit hot. At least it gets much hotter than I expected an LDO to get. Perhaps this is normal, it is certainly within the absolute maximum of 150C. On powering up the chip rapidly goes up from 23C room temp to about 60C on the plastic surface to about 80C on the ground tab and stays there.

The datasheet does have a Dropout Voltage Vdr versus Junction Temperature Tj (TLF80511TFV50), but I'm not sure I understand that chart exactly:

[image]

I feed the LDO 24V and it takes in about 150mA, now this is on the display of an uncalibrated bench voltage supply, so it may be a bit more or less. It's powering an Arduino Pro Mini + 5 other chips (TJA1051, MCP2515 and three PCF8575's which at the moment are kinda idle, they're connected but aren't programmed to do much at this time, most chips only take a few mA). I don't know how much mA the board takes, not sure how to measure this on a PCB..

Comment: Of all that data you post only **two** parameters are important in this respect: Current, 150 mA and voltage drop, you only mention a 24V input but no output voltage. My guess is that the output voltage is 5 V. So that's 24 V - 5 V = 21 V drop, at 150 mA that's 3.15 Watt. That means you will need to use a **heatsink**.

Comment: 24V input is far too high!

Comment: *At least it gets much hotter than I expected an LDO to get* How hot did you expect it to get? Instead of expectations, engineers rely on **calculations**. @LeonHeller It is not if you cool the LDO or if you do not want to cool it, make less current flow through it. Saying "24 V is too much", is not the complete story. This LDO *can* handle up to 45 V but power dissipation should be a consideration.

Comment: Here's a nice article from TI: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva462/slva462.pdf  in which it is shown how to do calculations with thermal resistances and heatsinks. You should aim for a **junction** temperature below 70 degrees C. Higher values can severely impact the lifetime of the IC. The fact that the chip currently heats up very quickly tells me that the cooling capacity is inadequate.

Comment: Why did you choose an LDO when you have 19V of headroom? Any linear regulator (including the ubiquitous 78xx series) would do the same job.

Comment: Thanks for the details, especially the aim for temp. is enlightening. I'll be moving to a switching power supply on the next version of the board. For the time being I've put a heatsink on it, which helps a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 24V in and 5V out you could have used a 7805, no need for a LDO. Or even better, a switching regulator, which would dissipate a lot less/

This LDO dissipates (24-5)*0.150 = 2.85W which is a lot for a SMD package. If you put enough vias, the heat will travel down the vias into the ground plane, which will act as a heat sink, but if the board is horizontal, airflow isn't as good as with a vertical heatsink with fins.

80°C on the tab is too much, the board must be quite hot, the lifetime of any nearby electrolytic capacitors will be shortened significantly. According to RthJC of 4°C/W junction temperature is around 91°C which is also a bit hot for comfort.

There is really no margin to add any extra loads. Again, for 24V to 5V, use a switching regulator instead, maybe a readymade one from Traco or Murata, there are many options.

Anyway, back to your question: the dropout curve. The LDO's pass element is a PMOS. The RdsON of this PMOS increases with temperature. The minimum dropout voltage occurs when the PMOS is fully on, thus dropout voltage is RdsON*I, and since RdsON increases with temperature, it follows that the minimum dropout voltage increases too.

This is not a concern here, as the dropout is 19V.

> I don't know how much mA the board takes, not sure how to measure this on a PCB..

Well you should have calculated this BEFORE using a LDO that will burn if it uses more than 200mA... again, not much margin for error here!

Comment: Thanks, and just to clarify, I did calculate the total theoretical mA usage, it's well below the 400mA that the LDO can output, just not sure how to reliably measure the actual usage. Somehow I was thinking an LDO was more efficient than it turned out. Next iteration I'll switch to a switching mode power supply.